# Facebook open graph error 100

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, share, facebook-opengraph

I used the following code, always keeps showing error

Error: Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 100.)" UserInfo=0x146472d0 {error_message=An error occurred while sharing an action., app_id=103673613161101, error_code=100}

Please help.

```
  -(void) openGraphTest
    {
        NSDictionary* author = [self.video objectForKey:@"author"];
        NSString *description =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"By %@", [author objectForKey:@"username"]];
        id<FBGraphObject> DiscoverObject =
        [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"discovermeapp:talent"
                                                title:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ - Episode %@",[[self.video objectForKey: @"video"] objectForKey: @"title" ],
                                                       [[self.video objectForKey: @"video"] objectForKey: @"episode_number"]]
                                                image:[[self.video objectForKey: @"video"] objectForKey: @"thumbnail_url"]
                                                  url:[[self.video objectForKey: @"video"] objectForKey: @"share_url"]
                                          description:description];

        id<FBOpenGraphAction> postAction = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
        [postAction setObject:DiscoverObject forKey:@"talent"];
       // [postAction setObject:@"true" forKey: @"fb:explicitly_shared"];


        [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:postAction
                                              actionType:@"discovermeapp:discover"
                                     previewPropertyName:@"Discover"
                                                 handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                     if(error) {
                                                         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                     } else {
                                                         NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                     }
                                                 }];
    }
```